# passport facebook- Case when User is logged out from facebook

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using [passport-facebook](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/) to handle facebook login for my website. Here is the relevant code:

**Less Important:**

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

            // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
            clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL

        },

        // facebook will send back the token and profile
        function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            // asynchronous
            process.nextTick(function () {
            //check for the user in db
            ...
            if(user found..){
               return done(null, user); // user found, return that user 
            }
            else{
                        // if there is no user found with that email id, create them
                        var newUser = {};
                        ............
                        return done(null, newUser);
             }
```

Serialise Deserialise:

```
// used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log('serializing user.');
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        getDBHandle(function (db) {
            db.collection('users').findOne({'id':id}, function (err, user) {
                console.log('deserialize user.',id,user);
                done(err, user);
            });
        });
    });
```

Caller:
// route for facebook authentication and login

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));
```

**Imporant**:
Once the user is logged in, then the loggedin user info is saved in `req.user` as per passport.

```
 app.get('/isAuthenticated',function(req,res){
       ...
       res.send(req.user);
    });
```

Now lets say, user logs out from her facebook account, how would passport knows that logout event has occured.

Essentially, if a user logs out from fb, then even our app should consider the user to be not logged in.

I tried calling `isAuthenticated` after I logout my fb, passport still returns same user information.

How should I handle this situation?

Do I need to call `/auth/facebook` everytime to check whether user is authenticated,  instead of depending upon `req.user`?

Comment: Wondering the same, did you manage to find a solution?